# Getting LookupField with SharePoint Online Management Shell

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, email, splistitem, pnp-powershell

I am trying to get the user `Email` through a LookUpField. When I try to "Write-Host the Email", the screen is blank. There is no errors and nothing. What is wrong with my code? Any help is much appreciated.

```
    ForEach ($ListItem in $ListItems){

    $lookUpField = $ListItem["uQmsResponsible"] -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue]       
    $user = $Web.EnsureUser($lookUpField.LookupValue.DisplayName);
    Write-Host $user.Email -ForegroundColor Cyan


}
```

> EDIT

Picture  of the listSettings(columns) for the list "Roller" that the LookupField "uQmsResponsible" is referencing :
[image]

Picture of what Lookupfield returns:

[image]

Comment: Can you debug it in the ISE? Does the $user variable have any value at all?

Comment: I have never debugged in ISE. Ill check it out right now. Any tips you can give me about ISE while I read up on it?

Comment: Is there value present in $lookUpField.LookupValue.DisplayName ? What's the value ? Can you try write host on that ?

Comment: Ran the code in ISE . $user does not have a value. I also realized I have to expand my search for email in the query. The returned values are the Id of a Role that the User has been given. The lists and all the data was already there when I started working on this project. I must have missed that the user Id is not in the LookUpField. Is there a way to retrive it with expand query?

Comment: can you share the query that you are using ? Also, what are you "looking" up to ? Is it a text column or something else ?

Comment: I´ll list all the info later in the evening. Not at the computer right now.

Comment: I dug around a bit in the lists and found that the LookupField "uQmsResponsible" contains a Id for an item in another list. in that list there is an coulmn named Email(textField). i upadated the question. How would I do to fetch the email now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the name of your column (uQmsResponsible) I guess it is of type "`Person or Group`". If that is the case, you should not cast your variable to `FieldLookupValue`, but to `FieldUserValue`. You could try with this code:

```
ForEach ($ListItem in $ListItems)
{
    $lookUpField = $ListItem["uQmsResponsible"] -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue]
    Write-Host $lookUpField.Email -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
```

Comment: I dug around a bit in the lists and found that the LookupField "uQmsResponsible" contains a Id for an item in another list. in that list there is an coulmn named Email(textField). i upadated the question. How would I do to fetch the email now?